# How to enter U-Boot command?

Tags: bootloader

I have a evaluation board with an android 8 firmware and U-boot boot loader. I want to enter U-boot prompt. My board mfr says I should press some keys when the system is booting to stop boot process but this is not worked at all. I press the borad keys and it has no effect. I use serial port with kermit terminal.

Have you any experience about entering U-boot prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The U-boot timeout (according to its configuration flags at compile time) may be as short as 2 seconds.

I use this way to enter the prompt:

1- Prepare serial port along with your terminal (like `ckermit`).

2- Reset the board and then send some arbitrary commands via serial.

The U-boot should stop autoboot process unless it is configured otherwise at compile time.

Comment: This worked for me. another question: do you know how to write mac address key via U-boot prompt? Thank you.

Comment: Start a new question. Comments are not proposed to be forums of discussion!

Comment: OK. here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567854/how-to-read-write-special-keys-via-u-boot-prompt)