# How to read/write special keys via U-boot prompt?

Tags: u-boot

How to write mac address and other special keys via U-boot prompt? Is there a general purpose command for this?

I know this can not be handled when the system is running as it deals with some security features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is somewhat depended on your hardware platform. My board uses `keyman` and `keyunify` commands. There can be found in U-boot help. Also the usage of these commands. 
For example:

```
keyman argv:
init seedNum <dtbAddr>
read keyname addr <hex/str>
write keyname size addr
write keyname hex/str value
query exist/secure/size keyname
exit
```

Another note: You said

> I know this can not be handled when the system is running as it deals
>   with some security features.

This may not be true. The keys can be accessed via unifykey driver (or something similar for your platform) and thereafter can be read/wrote. Consult you OS provider to find more.